# Converting a list of unicode objects to a list of strings

Tags: python, unicode, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a list of unicode objects `names` and I'm trying to produce a new list `parsed_names` so that the objects with a single name are converted to strings and the objects with a list of names are converted to a list of strings:

```
names = [u'Johnny', u'["Tamir", "Josh"]', u'Brad']
parsed_names = ['Johnny', ['Tamir', 'Josh'], 'Brad']
```

The following code does the trick but I'd rather not catch the error (`ValueError: malformed string`) in case something else were to go wrong:

```
import ast

names = [u'Johnny', u'["Tamir", "Josh"]', u'Brad']
parsed_names = []

for n in names:
    try:
        parsed_names.append(ast.literal_eval(name))
    except ValueError:
        parsed_names.append(str(name))

print parsed_names
# ['Johnny', ['Tamir', 'Josh'], 'Brad']
```

Note: My final goal is to produce a flattened list (`['Johnny', 'Tamir', 'Josh', 'Brad']`) but I already have code for that and I figure this step must be taken first.

Comment: Then the code won't work at all

Comment: @PatrickHaugh He's evaluating the strings first so that strings that looks like lists will be evaluated into lists. Everything that doesn't evaluate cleanly will be kept as strings.

Comment: You're going to run into problems by just evaluating each string. If someone's name is "True", you're going to get the boolean value `True` added to your final list. Any "name" that matches a builtin or reserved word is going to have problems.

Comment: @onlynone great point. I'm realizing that for integers as well. My data is a predetermined list of strings so I should be ok for the time being

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `extend` instead of `append` for sub-lists:

```
import ast

parsed_names = []
for n in names:
    try:
        sub_list = ast.literal_eval(n)
        parsed_names.extend(sub_list)
    except ValueError:
        parsed_names.append(str(n))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> parsed_names
['Johnny', 'Tamir', 'Josh', 'Brad']
```

If you do not want to use `try..except`, you can try the following:

```
temp = [ast.literal_eval(n) if '[' in n else str(n) for n in names]
#  ['Johnny', ['Tamir', 'Josh'], 'Brad']

res = []

for item in temp:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        res.extend(item)
    else:
        res.append(item)
```

Comment: Great! This solves my second question but I'm still worried about catching the error. If some other `ValueError` were to happen it won't be raised